# how to query a list of json object by key

Tags: elixir

I am new to `Elixir` and I have below list object:

`[{"user_id", "DPMJecfXsYMlYnM4dvUVUEjmV763"}, {"role", "admin"}, {"content-length", "0"}, {"host", "localhost:5000"}, {"connection", "close"}]`

The first value in each element is key and the second is the value. For example, `user_id` is the key, `DPMJecfXsYMlYnM4dvUVUEjmV763` is the value. How can I query this object by `key` in Elixir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted a keyword list. There is `Keyword.get` function, but it works only for atoms. So I would suggest converting to a map first, and then getting a value:

```
[
  {"user_id", "DPMJecfXsYMlYnM4dvUVUEjmV763"},
  {"role", "admin"},
  {"content-length", "0"},
  {"host", "localhost:5000"},
  {"connection", "close"}
]
|> Map.new
|> Map.get("user_id")
```

Comment: [Keyword.take/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#take/2) works with strings as well, in case you'd like to spare the time for the map conversion: `list |> Keyword.take ["user_id"]` will produce `[{"user_id", "DPMJecfXsYMlYnM4dvUVUEjmV763"}]`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [X-Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you are using `Plug`, what you really want to do is [get a response header from the connection](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#get_resp_header/2):

> `get_resp_header(conn, key)`
>
> Returns the values of the request header specified by key.
>
> **Examples**
>
> `iex> get_req_header(conn, "accept")`
>
> `["application/json"]`

So you could try: `Plug.Conn.get_resp_header(conn, "user_id")`